# Query about understanding the formulae which gives the Fourier series coefficients.

Tags: linear-algebra, fourier-series

Consider a periodic function $f(w)$, it can be expressed in terms of sins and cosines using a fourier series : $f(w)=\frac{a_0}{2}+ \sum{}_{n=1}^{\infty} a_ncos(nw)+b_nsin(nw) $.

I was trying to derive formula for the coefficients $a_n $ and $b_n$. My approach was to think of an analogy in terms of vectors. If a vector $\vec{A}$ is expressed in terms of 2 other vectors, example  $\vec{A} = a \vec{B} + b\vec{C}$, you can find the coefficients through taking a dot product of A with the normalised versions of vectors A, i.e $a = \vec{A} \cdot\hat{B}$ , $b = \vec{A} \cdot\hat{C}$.

So I thought it made sense here to the same, i.e:
$a_n = \int^{T+t_0}_{t_o}cos(nw)f(w) /\sqrt{\int^{T+t_0}_{t_o}cos^2(nw)}$ and $b_n= \int^{T+t_0}_{t_o}sin(nw)f(w) /\sqrt{\int^{T+t_0}_{t_o}sin^2(nw)}$. However, looking up the real answers, it seems to follow the same approach except the divisions by normalisation factors.

I just wanted to ask, why we dont divide through by the "magntiudes" of the $cos(nw)$ or $sin(nw)$ functions we are taking an inner product with? Where does my analogy with the ordinary vector dot product break down here?

Comment: Your analogy doesn't break down, it's just you have probably made a computation error or that the normalization constants are hidden somewhere. Note that your formula for the coefficients is not quite correct, you in fact have $a = \frac{ \vec{A} \cdot \hat{B}}{\| \vec{B} \|} = \frac{\vec{A} \cdot \vec{B}}{\| \vec{B} \|^2}$. Also $\cos(nw)$ and $\sin(nw)$ are not periodic on $[t_0, t_0 + T]$ unless $T = 2\pi$. For arbitrary period, you need to use a different orthogonal system (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series).

Comment: Can you please explain why my expression is not quite correct? I cant figure out why you need to divide through by the magnitude of $\vec{B}$, in your equation for $a$ above.

Comment: You have $\vec{A} \cdot \hat{B} = (a\vec{B} + b\vec{C}) \cdot \hat{B} = a \vec{B} \cdot \hat{B} = \left( a \| \vec{B} \| \right) \frac{\vec{B}}{\| \vec{B} \|} \cdot \hat{B} = \left( a \|\vec{B}\| \right) \hat{B} \cdot \hat{B} = a \| \vec{B} \|$.

Comment: But isnt $\vec{A} \cdot\hat{B} = \mid{A}\mid \mid{\hat{B}}\mid cos\theta  =\mid{A}\mid cos\theta =$component of A we want?

Comment: If you would have written $\vec{A} = a \hat{B} + b \hat{C}$ then indeed $a = \vec{A} \cdot \hat{B}$ (note the hats) but you have written $\vec{A} = a \vec{B} + b \vec{C}$ and this changes the formula.